# I'd like to reproduce the notification system of Twitter and Instagram

Tags: swift

I'm trying to divide my view controller in two different parts accessing by swiping right or left, exactly like the notifications of Twitter and Instagram.

[image: twitter notifications]

I don't know what's the name for this design so my research on Google aren't successful. I tried to do it by myself. I have a view controller in which there is a view containing the 2 sections labels with the cursor below and a view container containing a page view controller to enable swiping. I can swipe between the 2 sections but I don't know how to move the cursor and change the color and weight of the labels when swiping between the 2.

[image: simulator of what I have done]

Here is my view code where I draw the line and the cursor :

```swift
class LineView: UIView {

    let cursor = CAShapeLayer()

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let line = UIBezierPath()
        line.lineWidth = 1
        line.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        line.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width,y: 0))
        UIColor.lightGray.setStroke()
        line.stroke()

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: 0))
        cursor.path = path.cgPath
        cursor.strokeColor = UIColor(red:1.00, green:0.09, blue:0.40, alpha:1.0).cgColor
        cursor.lineWidth = 2

        layer.addSublayer(cursor)
    }
}
```

and the code of my page view controller :

```swift
class HomePageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    lazy var viewControllerList : [UIViewController] = {
       let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewController1 = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PublicViewController")
        let viewController2 = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PrivateViewController")

        return [viewController1, viewController2]
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.dataSource = self

        if let firstViewController = viewControllerList.first {
            self.setViewControllers([firstViewController], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let index = viewControllerList.firstIndex(of: viewController) else { return nil }
        let previousIndex = index - 1
        guard previousIndex >= 0 else { return nil }
        guard viewControllerList.count > previousIndex else { return nil }
        return viewControllerList[previousIndex]
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let index = viewControllerList.firstIndex(of: viewController) else { return nil }
        let nextIndex = index + 1
        guard viewControllerList.count != nextIndex else { return nil }
        guard viewControllerList.count > nextIndex else { return nil }
        return viewControllerList[nextIndex]
    }

}
```

I'm not sure this is the right way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use collection view for header, i.e. **Public** and **Private**.

For controller I have placed `UIScrollView` inside view controller of storyboard. 
Then after added two container view inside scrollview with equal with and height respect to scrollView. Regarding code you can download below project.

Here is the full demo project what you want: [CustomStepperController](https://github.com/sagar4893/CustomStepperController)

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm gonna check your project! Is is better to use a collection view rather than a simple view for the header? What's the difference?

Comment: By using `UICollectionView` you can add any number of header, and due to cell reuse it will save memory.